# Completely disable popup blocker on one site

Tags: firefox, popups

In Google Reader, I am using <kbd>V</kbd> to open pages in new tabs. Because Firefox's popup blocker doesn't see this as a “legitimate” action that is allowed to open a new tab, I have added www.google.com to the popup blocker exceptions.

This works fine most of the time, but when I open many tabs (about 20) in one go, the new tab is blocked and any following ones are too. Is there some way to “force” the exception, so that it won't block any popups from the sites I set, no matter how many of new tabs do I open?

I do not want to turn off the popup blocker completely, just for this one site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have hit the Firefox limit of [dom.popup_maximum](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.popup_maximum), defined as
"The number of pop-ups to allow from a single non-click event. (Default: 20).".

To change this limit :

- Type `about:config` in the URL bar and hit Enter.
- Type in the Search box : `dom.popup_maximum`. The default value is 20.
- Double-click the entry and try something higher.